# What is causing my autocomplete to not show the correct text color

Tags: css, angular-material

I have a problem I cannot figure out at all. I have implemented an `md-autocomplete` element into my app that I first tested on codepen. I cannot figure out why the text color differs. I have included the computed css and a picture of how it's supposed to look - I'm unsure as to how to make it dark text on my application as it is on my snippet.

The css class is `md-autocomplete-suggestions` and for the non-working one it's both `md-autocomplete-suggestions` and `autocomplete-custom-template` (which i cannot find the styling to).

This is **the working one**:
note: this is using the default [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) css

[image]
[image]

And here is **the non-working one** (note: it has text and it works, but the text seems either transparent or white):

[image]
[image]

Please let me know if any other information is needed. It is a gigantic css file on my app, so it will be tough to replicate on

Comment: Is this live somewhere? The broken example in particular.

Comment: @SergChernata No, sorry. I could add any other data, just let me know what you need specifically.

Comment: Need to see a live example

Comment: let me see what i can do